# Trying to create mapping from visual foxpro tables to entity framework using VFP Entity Framework Provider

Tags: database, entity-framework, code-first, visual-foxpro

I was following this tutorial about mapping from visual foxpro tables to entity framwork using VFP Entity Framework Provider [Using VFP Entity Framework Provider With Free Tables Using Code First](https://randomdevnotes.com/2012/05/06/using-vfp-entity-framework-provider-with-free-tables-using-code-first.)

But when I try to do Reverse Engineer then I get this error in the Output window:

> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The store provider factory type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbFactory' does not implement the IServiceProvider interface. Use a store provider that implements this interface.
>      at System.Data.Entity.Design.Common.MetadataUtil.GetProviderServices(DbProviderFactory factory)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator.CreateStoreSchemaConnection(String providerInvariantName, String connectionString, Version targetEntityFrameworkVersion)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Design.SsdlGenerator.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.CreateStoreSchemaConnection(String providerInvariantName, String connectionString, Version& storeSchemaModelVersion)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator..ctor(String providerInvariantName, String connectionString, String namespaceName)
>      at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Handlers.ReverseEngineerCodeFirstHandler.ReverseEngineerCodeFirst(Project project)

Entity Framework version 6
Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4
VFP Entity Framework Provider version 2.0.5.0

Comment: It's crazy to try to stay with VFP tables.  The latest upsizing wizard works great and so does this tool:  http://www.whitetown.com/dbf2sql/

Comment: There is a reason to stay with VFP tables in this project, I have to work with these tables not convert them to SQL

Comment: @Missy your comment is totally irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in the same website, just follow the instructions here

https://randomdevnotes.com/2013/12/15/visual-foxpro-entity-framework-provider-v2-getting-started-with-code-first/